# How to check if an App is running in BlueStacks

Tags: c#, bluestacks

I'm wondering how could I check if an app is running inside the BlueStacks Application which simulates Android apps.

In my code, I'm using this line below to start the app, but how can I check if its already running? **Note: The check function must work even tho the app has not been initialized by the code-line below. Lets suppose I started manually the app on bluestacks and then I request the check function**

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:/Program Files (x86)/BlueStacks/HD-RunApp.exe", "-p com.supercell.clashofclans -a com.supercell.clashofclans.GameApp");
```

The application mentioned as an example: *Clash of Clans*

At task manager, the process **HD-Frontend.exe** is shown whether im using the app i started or not. Which means i cannot use the process name to check if its running because it wont work properly.

```
    private bool appRunning()
    {
        var runningProcessByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("HD-Frontend");
        if (runningProcessByName.Length == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: Are you interested in whether _any_ instance of `HD-RunApp.exe` is running, the one you started, or a specific instance?

Comment: @CodeCaster the one I started

Comment: Then save the returned `Process` instance from `Process.Start()`.

Comment: What you mean? This is how it is right now

        private bool appRunning()
        {
            var runningProcessByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("HD-Frontend");
            if (runningProcessByName.Length == 0)
            { return true;
            }else {
                return false;}
        }

Comment: `var startedProcess = Process.Start("C:\\Program...`. Then you can operate on the `startedProcess` instance.

Comment: Wont work properly. Because I dont want to necessarily execute the app. i just want to check incase its already manually executed

Comment: Then don't say "the one I started".

Comment: Misunderstood, sorry. What am i supposed to do then?